# SELECT in Mysql Trigger returns NULL for integer and date fields

Tags: mysql, select, triggers

I use a SELECT on TABLE2 in a before or a after INSERT Trigger of TABLE1.
The select gets varchar, date and integer values.
Only varchar are returned. All others values are set to NULL.

```
DECLARE d_enl date;
    DECLARE d_liv date;
    DECLARE d_trace_enl date;
    DECLARE d_trace_liv date;
    DECLARE ecart_enl int;
    DECLARE ecart_liv int(8);   
    DECLARE h_min varchar(8);
    DECLARE h_max varchar(8);

SELECT D_ENL, D_LIV INTO d_enl, d_liv FROM refer WHERE K_REFER = NEW.K_REFER;       

SELECT H_LIV_MIN, H_LIV_MAX INTO h_min, h_max FROM refer WHERE K_REFER = NEW.K_REFER;

SELECT ECART_ENL INTO ecart_enl FROM refer WHERE K_REFER = NEW.K_REFER;
```

K_REFER is PRIMARY UNIQUE KEY, so only one row is returned.
I tried a select with all fields, a select for each type like, and even a select by variable using SET var1  = (SELECT Field1 FROM ... WHERE).

Same result : h_min and h_max (varchar) are set. Other variables are null. Of course, none of the fields are null in the record selected.

Comment: Name your local variables distinctly from your column names. Yes, column names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks @Bill....

Comment: No thanks for the one who downvote, I spend hours (and it's now ten pm, friday evening...), so "no effort"... "LOL !". Variables not case sensitive... It's a bit weird on Linux. And it's very stange that Mysql did not send any error or warning when you select fields into same fields... It's a bit poor for such database. Anyway... As delete trigger are even not fired when delete by constraints, not a surprise...

Comment: For the record, I did not downvote. But I recommend you don't worry about downvotes. There are thousands — millions — of users on Stack Overflow. If any one of them doesn't like your question for any reason, they can give you a downvote. This system is naturally biased toward downvotes.

Comment: I didn't think you was the one who downvoted Bill ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from variable name. It seems that they are not case sensitive ? So the query is confused about variables with same name as fields.